# Send data between activities error on intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, maps

I'm trying to send data from an overlay to other activity with this class

```
public class Capas extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> 

{
MapView Map;
 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context mContext;

 public Capas(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
 {
 super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
 mContext = context;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
 {   
     if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
         GeoPoint puntoTocado = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
         Intent nuevoLugar=new Intent(Capas.this,editarLugar.class);
         nuevoLugar.putExtra("latitud",puntoTocado.getLatitudeE6());
         nuevoLugar.putExtra("longitud",puntoTocado.getLongitudeE6());
         StartActivity()


     }                            
     return false;
 }
```

}

But this return me the next error The constructor Intent(Capas, Class) is undefined.
 I try with              `Intent nuevoLugar=new Intent(Capas.class,editarLugar.class);`               `Intent nuevoLugar=new Intent(this,editarLugar.class);` but anoone works

Comment: When I'm make the intent mContecxt return me null and the app crash, how i inizialice mContext?

Comment: You should look at where you instantiate the Capas object. Do you call `new Capas(marker, null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case this should work:

```
Intent nuevoLugar = new Intent(mContext, editarLugar.class);
```

Provided that `editarLugar extends Activity` and is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
And to start the activity:

```
mContext.startActivity(nuevoLugar);
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a a new intent you need to get access to a `Context` instance. `ItemizedOverlay` doesn't extend from it.

You have you initialize the intent like this:

```
Intent nuevoLugar=new Intent(mContext, editarLugar.class);
```

You need to make sure that `editarLugar` is an `Activity`.

<strike>But also, you need access to the activity. Since I think we can assume that you are creating it from an Activity you can launch it like this:</strike>

```
if(mContext instanceof Activity) {
    ((Activity)mContext).startActivity(nuevoLugar);
}
```

My bad, you can just call:

```
mContext.startActivity(nuevoLugar);
```

Comment: Also a good read: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html ;)

Comment: Context.startActivity() method is also available. So you don't need cast there.

Answer (score 2):

the first argument should be a Context. please try Intent nuevoLugar=new Intent(mContext,editarLugar.class);